# Could not load type System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<somethig>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I spend all day trying to find the solution. I found some but none of it worked for me. Long short the application I am working on is being upgraded from MVC3 (I believe) to MVC5 and ASP.NET Version 4.6.1. The upgrades were being done by some other developer and now I have to fix all issues and bugs he left. The issue I am facing is that I can't load strongly typed view. I invoke the action method from my main view:

```
<div id="fromLocationEditPartial">
     @Html.Action("FormLocationEdit", "Shared", new { area = "Shared", options = Model.LocationID });
</div>
```

Here is the action method code I am calling:

```
 public ActionResult FormLocationEdit(int? options)
    {
        LocationEditorModel model = new LocationEditorModel();

        //DTLocationAutoMetadata locObj;
        DTLocation locObj;

        if (options.HasValue)
        {
            int locationID = options.Value;
            //locObj = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<DTLocation, DTLocationAutoMetadata>(entities.DTLocation.Where(m => m.LocationID == locationID).FirstOrDefault());
            locObj = entities.DTLocation.Where(m => m.LocationID == locationID).FirstOrDefault();

            if (locObj == null)
            {
                locObj = new DTLocation();
                locObj.SelectLocation = new SelectList(model.GetListOfLocations(), "Value", "Text");
            }
            else
            {
                locObj.SelectLocation = new SelectList(model.GetListOfLocations(), "Value", "Text", locObj.SiteID);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            locObj = null;
        }

        return View("~/Areas/Shared/Views/FormLocationEdit.ascx", locObj);
    }
```

Here as you can see it suppose to return the strongly typed view with object. 
Here is how my shared view looks like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<CMDBv3.DTLocationAutoMetadata>" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
    //BindSubmitActions('formLocationEdit');
   })
</script>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("FormLocationEdit", "Shared", FormMethod.Post,  new { area="Shared", id = "formLocationEdit" })) {%>
***here is the condition if (Model!=null) do something else display model data***
```

In my VS Error list I am having errors:

> Error 4   The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context
>   Error 2   The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context

When I run the proj I am getting inner exception:

> Could not load type System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl"<"CMDBv3.DTLocationAutoMetadata">"

As I understand it is some issues with versioning but I checked all my web.config and it seems that version is fine there. Can someone give me some advice what else could it be if it is not web.config issue?

Comment: You might find that its easier to simply create a new MVC 5 Application and copy+paste over the relevant code. Upgrading MVC apps seems harder than it should be, for even 1 version increase, whereas you are jumping from v3 to v5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it just simply created cshtml view and use razor syntax:

```
@model CMDBv3.DTLocation

@using (Html.BeginForm("FormLocationEdit", "Shared", FormMethod.Post, new { 
area = "Shared", id = "formLocationEdit" }))
```

and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem in the past when upgrading MVC 3 (or 4) project using ASCX shared user controls inside area into MVC 5 with Razor views enabled by default (missing `ViewUserControl` namespace), hence I trying to add these lines below on web.config file inside Views directory of that area and working properly then:

```
<system.web>
    <pages validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
     pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
     userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <controls>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

NB: This change also apply to other area views' web.config containing ASPX page/ASCX controls which inherit `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage`/`System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl`.

Then, in that area view's web.config, ensure these lines added between `system.web.webPages.razor` element:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

To solve "Model doesn't exist" issue, you can change this line in project's web.config:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
```

To this line:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

For further info about upgrading to MVC 5, check [MVC 5 Upgrade Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642329/some-official-or-not-upgrade-mvc3-to-mvc5-guide).

PS: The missing namespaces problem often occurs when web.config file inside `Views` directory (including area views) not included or not created yet. Also if you're still not sure try setting `Copy Local = True` in reference properties related with `System.Web.Mvc` namespace. After all, seems it is easier to create a new predefined MVC 5 project and resolving relevant existing resources into that.

Related issues:

[Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SOMETYPE>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803408/could-not-load-type-system-web-mvc-viewusercontrolsometype)

["The name 'HTML' does not exist in the current context" in MVC 3 Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548608/the-name-html-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-in-mvc-3-views)

[Razor View throwing "The name 'model' does not exist in the current context"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696963/razor-view-throwing-the-name-model-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)